# Ошибка после выгрузки проекта на локальный сервер

Tags: php, битрикс, 1с

После того, как выгрузил проект на локальный сервер и интерпретировал дамп начала появляться ошибка. 
[image]

Comment: Это трейс вызовов. Текст ошибки выше. Этот текст тоже хотелось бы увидеть.

Comment: Вся проблема в том, что кроме этого там ничего нет.

Comment: Такого не может быть. А что в html-коде страницы отображается?

Comment: по всей видимости он не может подключиться к мускулу и нужно установить корректные данные для доступа к БД и проверить что она доступна

Comment: <html>
  <head><head>
 <body>
    <pre>
  все трейсы
    </pre>
</body>
</html>

Comment: Я могу вам куда-нибудь скрины скинуть ?

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: прикрепите код .settings.php и dbconn.php обычно это ошибка возникает если драйвер на mysqli не обнаружен а в настройках стоит mysqli поменяйте в .settings.php в ключе className строку \\Bitrix\\Main\\DB\\MysqliConnection на \\Bitrix\\Main\\DB\\MysqlConnection и так же переменную в $DBType с mysqli на mysql и перезагрузите сервер